# How to write $1 in regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex program which does not repeat unit in series.
i want to capture the unit,here it is CM.

```
<?php
$match = '4 CM,6.5 CM,8 CM,9.6 cm and 10 CM';
if(preg_match('/\d+\s?(\w+)(?!$)/i',$match))
{
$out = preg_replace('/ $1(?!$)/i', '', $match);
echo $out;
}
?>
```

sample input:

```
4 CM,6.5 CM,8 CM,9.6 cm and 10 CM
```

output:

```
4,6.5,8,9.6 and 10 CM
```

please help me out.

Comment: Oh! You want to **detect** that the *same* unit was used for all terms and **remove** it from all but the last one? Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found correct way of doing it.
Add $matches in preg_match.It is an array.

```
preg_match('/ \d+\s?\.?(\w+)?/',$match, $matches);
$out = preg_replace('/'.$matches[1].'(?!$)/', '', $match);
```

On printing $matches we know $matches[1] contains cm.

```
Array ( [0] => 10 cm [1] => cm )
```